# How to connect a seconds timer to a minutes timer in Swift?

Tags: swift, timer

I have created a setupGame and subtractScore class for both minutes and seconds, so both the minutes and seconds timers work as of now. However, I cannot figure out how to make the minutes timer decrement by one every time the seconds timer gets to zero. Essentially I've tried to use if statements (e.g. if(seconds == 0) {minutes = minutes - 1}), but that has had no effect.

Comment: You should take a look at NSTimeInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use separate timers. Have a seconds timer that fires once a second.
It sounds like you want a count-down timer. So...

Record the time when the timer starts using code like this:

```
let secondsToEnd = 60*5
let startInterval =  NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
let endInterval = startInterval + Double(secondsToEnd)
```

Then in your timer code:

```
let remainingSeconds = Int(endInterval - NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
let minutes = remainingSeconds/60
let seconds = remainingSeconds%60
```

Display the minutes and seconds values however you need to.

NSTimers will sometimes miss a firing if the app is busy when the timer should have gone off, and are not super-accurate. The above code will always calculate the *real* remaining amount of time, regardless of the timer you use to display that info and any inaccuracy in that timer.